# Swift: Difference between prepareForSegue and instantiateViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to get more of a generic solution to the navigation in my project and I have been wondering about segues vs. manually instantiated VCs.

The way I do it atm is, that I have all possible segues from one view to another set in Storyboard and call them on touch of the specific elements.

e.g:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

            let c = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailVC

            let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
            let myPath: AnyObject = indexPath[0]
            let post = self.myCollection[myPath.item].id

            println(post)

            controller?.thisPost = post

        }
    //else do stuff for other identifiers
}
```

Unfortunately as there are a lot of control items allowing the user to invoke almost all possible views from everywhere this ends up being a total segue chaos in Storyboard.

What I actually want is to completely delete all segues in storyboard and call my next VC out programmatically, depending on what item was tapped.

i.e. something along the lines of:

```
var nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailVC") as! DetailVC
let itemToShow = //collectionView selected cell.id
nextVC.thisPost = itemToShow
self.presentViewController(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I am actually stuck at configuring the nextVC string "thisPost" before showing the View. In opposite to prepareForSegue it doesn't let me access nextVC.thisPost.

Do I have to do this via protocol/delegate as the VC is not yet configurable or am I just missing out on a detail?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to configure the nextVC string "thisPost" by presenting view controller programmatically as well but you have to force unwrap nextVC first since `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailVC") as! DetailVC` returns an optional value because of question mark after `self.storyboard?` or you can also choose to force unwrap storyboard itself

So you can choose between first option that would look like this :

```
var nextVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailVC") as! DetailVC
let itemToShow = //collectionView selected cell.id
nextVC!.thisPost = itemToShow
self.presentViewController(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or the second one :

```
var nextVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailVC") as! DetailVC
let itemToShow = //collectionView selected cell.id
nextVC.thisPost = itemToShow
self.presentViewController(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: so the storyboard? overrules the as! cast in my version? and sets the whole nextVC as Optional(DetaliVC) ?

Comment: Yes thats right. By placing `?` after `storyboard` means that if storyboard is nil return nil immediately  if not call its `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method